# mvim highlighting long text works sporadically

Tags: vim

I am using mvim. I have following lines in my vimrc .

```
"highlight text that goes over 80 columns
highlight OverLength ctermbg=red ctermfg=white guibg=#592929
match OverLength /\%81v.*/
```

Sometimes in my project I see the extra characters highlighted and sometimes I don't . I mean once vim is displaying extra characters then it will continue to display extra characters. However if I get out of vim and start vim instance it might not highlight extra characters. To fix that I type

```
match OverLength /\%81v.*/
```

I am puzzled by why it is happening. Is it possible that some plugin is messing with these settings?

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that a plugin is undoing it by setting its own `match`. It's also possible that you're creating a new window. `match` is per-window (not per-buffer, and not global) so it only applies to the window that was active when the `match` command was executed.

You can try creating an autocmd to set up the match on new windows:

```
au! WinEnter match OverLength /\%81v.*/
```

Note that this is not executed on the first window.

Comment: You are right when I create a new tab in the existing window then I do not get the highlights. I did not notice that until you pointed out. Lemme try your suggestion.

Comment: I put in your code in vimrc file like this.

"highlight text that goes over 80 columns
highlight OverLength ctermbg=red ctermfg=white guibg=#592929
match OverLength /\%81v.*/
"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1608385/mvim-highlighting-long-text-works-sporadically
au! WinEnter match OverLength /\%81v.*/


I still have the same problem. When I create a new tab then I do not see the highlights. I am using mac. I saw WinEnter and thought may be solution will work only on windows.

Comment: Ah, yeah, for tabs you need to use TabEnter.

Comment: TabEnter did not do it. First tab is highlighted second one is not.

Answer (score 0):

Well I had the same problem when using new Tabs in MacVim 7.3 (Snapshot 56). When opening a new window the highlighting worked, but when I opened a new Tab it did not work anymore. So I added the following autocommand to my .vimrc file:

```
autocmd BufWinEnter,BufRead * match OverLength /\%81v.\+/
```

Now it works for me, in any new window or tab and buffer.

I hope this will help!

Comment: Found another site dealing with this problem. Looks the author found a nice solution, that works in tabs, (v)splits and adds a proximity highlight as well. 
Link: https://wincent.com/blog/highlighting-overlength-lines-in-vim